# WooCommerce: Get the cart item quantity of a customized product only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I have modified the functions.php file to include the possibility of customizing certain products with custom text.

This feature comes with an extra cost of 1 which will be shown on product checkout unless the feature hasn't been fulfilled:

```
    if (!empty( $cart_item['custom_text'] ) ) {

        $surcharge = 1;
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Customization', $surcharge, true, '' );
    }
```

Naturally, if more customized products are added to the cart, this 1 should be multiplicated by the number of products in the cart. I've tried adding the variable $quantity for this purpose:

```
    if (!empty( $cart_item['custom_text'] ) ) {
            
        $quantity = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

        $surcharge = 1 * $quantity;
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Customization', $surcharge, true, '' );
    }
```

The problem here is if the client attempts to buy a customized item but not the other, since this method takes into account the total quantity in the cart regardless of it's customized or not. See figure 1:

[image: Figure 1]

So the question is: is it possible to get only the customized items (circled in green in figure 1) to calculate the surcharge?

Comment: Well `get_cart_contents_count` only gets you the overall number of items in the cart. You need to get the number of times your _specific_ customized item(s) were put into the cart instead. `get_cart_item_quantities` is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the cart item quantity for your customized product only use the following:

```
if (!empty( $cart_item['custom_text'] ) ) {
    $surcharge = 1;
    $quantity  = $cart_item['quantity'];
    WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Customization', ( $surcharge * $quantity ), true, '' );
}
```

It should works as you are expecting

Comment: Your solution was very useful. However after further testing I've come to realize that this gets only the quantity of the first item in cart (provided that the custom_text is not empty).

The next customized items are not counted for the surcharge. Would you know how to overcome this?

Comment: @vsilvestre22 Ask a new question providing your **complete** related code (not just an excerpt of it)… Without your complete code people can't understand what is involved and give you the required help. In your new question try to explain what is working, what doesn't work and what you expect. When it's done notify me here.

Comment: sorry! I was just thinking on editing this post but then I saw your comment. I will ask a new question with the complete code and take this one for answered as it answers well the initial question. Thank you again!